# How to import template made by webpack into Laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, webpack, sass, laravel-mix

I am developing a Laravel project. And I am using a third party HTML template which is using webpack and laravel mix to compile all assets. I need to know is there any way to import that HTML template to Laravel and compile it within the Laravel project. I am new to frontend technologies like webpack/laravel mix. It would be great if anyone can guide me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Laravel, but since you have NodeJS in your stack, you should be able to incorporate a build step for copying templates into wherever Laravel needs them (I guess /assets/templates?)

Something like this perhaps?

```
const fs = require('fs')
webpack(webpackConfig, error => {
  if (error) console.error(error)
  else {
    fs.copyFileSync('generatedTemplate.js', '/assets/templates')
  }
})
```

I can't offer much more advice without knowing your setup. I think utilizing NodeJS is the solution here though.

Comment: I added the files manually to Laravel project (Sass and Js). and compiled it using. It was successfully compiled. But with few errors. Then what I did was I compiled the template separately and added Js and css files to Laravel and mapped them.